# Escape sequence char as a list string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a list like this:

```
signs = ['/', '-', '\']
```

I get `EOL error` probably because of `\`

So I updated the list to :

```
signs = ["/", "-", "'\'"]

# output ['/', '-', "''"]
```

Silly to ask but how do I get the list with `\` as a string present in the list, so I can iterate over them.

Comment: you have to double the backslash `'\\'`

Comment: I tried your suggestion it gives me the `\\` string.

Comment: I mean `signs = ['/', '-', '\\']`

Comment: Yes, I tried `signs = ['/','-','\\']` got this `['/', '-', '\\']`, can you confirm please.

Comment: using @Jean-FrançoisFabre suggestion instead of doing `print(signs)` do a loop `for s in signs: print(s)` and that will print each character/sign appropriately

Comment: @depperm, works. I guess it doesn't evaluate it while printing.